# how set simple timeout?

Tags: javascript, angular

I, is possible to write one setTimeout , non 2 call setTimeOut ?

```js
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {

  public cacheMenu = "block";
  public burger = ""
//
//i try this

setTimeout(//on cache le menu au bout de 2 seconde
  () => 
  this.cacheMenu = "none", 2000,
  this.burger = "croix", 2000 //burger is not wait 2 seconde!
);


  bascule() {

    this.show = !this.show;
    this.sendBasculContact.emit();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
   
  onSelectMenu() {
    setTimeout(//on cache le menu au bout de 2 seconde
      () => 
      this.cacheMenu = "none", 2000
    );

    setTimeout(//on cache le menu au bout de 2 seconde
      () => 
      this.burger = "croix", 2000
    );
  }
```

I try one setTimeout with séparte virgule ","  but this.burger is not wait to load "croix"

thank's for reply

Comment: Just put one inside the other, instead of putting them in the same block?

Comment: i try      setTimeout(//on cache le menu au bout de 2 seconde
      () => 
      this.cacheMenu = "none", 2000,
      this.burger = "croix", 2000
    );, but burger is load now not wait 2 seconde

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just do both statements in the same timeout function.

```
onSelectMenu() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.cacheMenu = "none";
        this.burger = "croix";
    }, 2000);
};
```

When you execute multiple statements in an arrow function you have to put `{}` around the body.

Comment: Thanks, i disrupt a ";" with ",", now my snippet is ok

Comment: @geekpédagogiquelcms: You wanted this?

Answer (score 0):

I think, what you want is to run second time out after the first one completes:

```
onSelectMenu() {
    setTimeout(
    () => {
       this.cacheMenu = "none"
       setTimeout(
          () => {
              this.burger = "croix"
           }, 2000
       )
    }, 2000);
}
```